# Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined React Js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

How to display author.name data from JSON file because I am getting an error when I try to run I am new in react js so guide me how to solve this error, I also added error page image so you can see

```
class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            question: [],
          };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://trivago-magazine-work-sample-server.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dornoch-castle-scotland-whisky.json`)
      .then(res => {
        const question = res.data;
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ question });
      })

  }


    render() {
        const {question} = this.state;

        if (question === null) return <p>Loading ...</p>;
        return (
            <div>

            <Container>
                <Row >

                    <h4>{question.author.name}</h4> //This Line when i try to show author.name it showing error 

                </Row>
            </Container>



            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Details
```

[Here is the image of error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycFOR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial state should be `{ question: null }`, so that `if (question === null)` takes effect and renders the "Loading..." message.

Answer (score -1):

first change :

```
this.state = {
         question: null,
          };
```

and you have to put a condition if there is a question :

```
{question && 
   <h4>{ question.author.name}</h4> 
}
```